# Failed to execute stat function during MySql 5.7 installation

Tags: server, 18.04, mysql

When I am trying to install MySql server 5.7, I am getting loads of errors saying that the the system couldn't execute stat function on file /proc/{number_of_digits}/fd/{number_of_digits}: access denied.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.02.

The command I am using is:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client-5.7
```

The console output is as follows:

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client-5.7
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Будут установлены следующие дополнительные пакеты:
  mysql-server-5.7
Предлагаемые пакеты:
  mailx tinyca
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 4 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/5 526 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 82,0 MB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
Предварительная настройка пакетов ...
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета mysql-common.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 166049 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/mysql-common_5.8+1.0.4_all.deb …
Распаковывается mysql-common (5.8+1.0.4) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета mysql-client-5.7.
Подготовка к распаковке …/mysql-client-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) …
Настраивается пакет mysql-common (5.8+1.0.4) …
update-alternatives: используется /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback для предоставления /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) в автоматическом режиме
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета mysql-server-5.7.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 166097 файлов и каталогов.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb …
Распаковывается mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) …
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета mysql-server.
Подготовка к распаковке …/mysql-server_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_all.deb …
Распаковывается mysql-server (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для ureadahead (0.100.0-20) …
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (237-3ubuntu10.20) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) …
Настраивается пакет mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) …
Настраивается пакет mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) …
update-alternatives: используется /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf для предоставления /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) в автоматическом режиме
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1778/fd/1023: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/5: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/9: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/10: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/67: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/68: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/1023: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1842/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1842/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1842/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1842/fd/9: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1842/fd/10: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1842/fd/11: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1855/fd/4: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1855/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1855/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1855/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/9: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/10: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/11: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/15: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1864/fd/16: Отказано в доступе
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Настраивается пакет mysql-server (5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для systemd (237-3ubuntu10.20) …
Обрабатываются триггеры для ureadahead (0.100.0-20) …
:~$
```

The `Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/1830/fd/7: Отказано в доступе` is translated as `Failed to run stat function for file /proc/1830/fd/7: Access denied`.

The contents of the error log at `/var/log/mysql/error.log` are as follows:

```
2019-04-21T19:19:58.752909Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-04-21T19:20:00.035823Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2019-04-21T19:20:00.186098Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-04-21T19:20:00.429276Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 75082f61-646a-11e9-ab51-88b111908d1e.
2019-04-21T19:20:00.431277Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2019-04-21T19:20:00.435244Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.351625Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-04-21T19:20:06.353781Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 2979 ...
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361029Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361088Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361099Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361109Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361120Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361130Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361456Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-04-21T19:20:06.361583Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-04-21T19:20:06.363789Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-04-21T19:20:06.376001Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-04-21T19:20:06.379089Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-04-21T19:20:06.392807Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.550788Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-04-21T19:20:06.550974Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-04-21T19:20:06.649485Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.650664Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.650711Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.651318Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-04-21T19:20:06.701805Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log sequence number 2524544
2019-04-21T19:20:06.702440Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-04-21T19:20:06.702665Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.706872Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190421 20:20:06
2019-04-21T19:20:06.714749Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-04-21T19:20:06.871083Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.883144Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-04-21T19:20:06.883834Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.BVvmN5MQbL/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu)
2019-04-21T19:20:06.916387Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-04-21T19:20:06.916435Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-04-21T19:20:06.916448Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-04-21T19:20:06.916461Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-04-21T19:20:06.916519Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917270Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917315Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917323Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917331Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917340Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917348Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917381Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917390Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917402Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917411Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917419Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917426Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917433Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917440Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917447Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917454Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917460Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917467Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917474Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917481Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917488Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917494Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917501Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917508Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917515Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917521Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917528Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917535Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917542Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917548Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917555Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917562Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917568Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917575Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917582Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917589Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917596Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917602Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917609Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2019-04-21T19:20:06.917676Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-04-21T19:20:06.918778Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-04-21T19:20:07.019320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-04-21T19:20:07.019829Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190421 20:20:07
2019-04-21T19:20:08.783616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2524765
2019-04-21T19:20:08.785800Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-04-21T19:20:08.785832Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2019-04-21T19:20:08.785844Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-04-21T19:20:08.785855Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2019-04-21T19:20:08.785862Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2019-04-21T19:20:08.786129Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2019-04-21T19:20:08.786579Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-04-21T19:20:09.705767Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-04-21T19:20:09.708082Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 3029 ...
2019-04-21T19:20:09.715320Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-04-21T19:20:09.715389Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-04-21T19:20:09.715407Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-04-21T19:20:09.715418Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-04-21T19:20:09.715435Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-04-21T19:20:09.715446Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-04-21T19:20:09.715904Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-04-21T19:20:09.716038Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-04-21T19:20:09.718219Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-04-21T19:20:09.731523Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-04-21T19:20:09.734813Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-04-21T19:20:09.748250Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-04-21T19:20:09.906468Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-04-21T19:20:09.906600Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-04-21T19:20:10.022094Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.023359Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.023407Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.023890Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-04-21T19:20:10.074378Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log sequence number 2524765
2019-04-21T19:20:10.075115Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-04-21T19:20:10.075284Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.080184Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190421 20:20:10
2019-04-21T19:20:10.086722Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-04-21T19:20:10.086793Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2019-04-21T19:20:10.086825Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-04-21T19:20:10.086942Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.240463Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.250441Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-04-21T19:20:10.250666Z 0 [Note] Execution of init_file '/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.PwGnsNqN2P' started.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.251845Z 0 [Note] Execution of init_file '/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.PwGnsNqN2P' ended.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.252045Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.iTjbzQstcd/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
2019-04-21T19:20:10.252670Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2019-04-21T19:20:10.252719Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2019-04-21T19:20:10.252728Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2019-04-21T19:20:10.252741Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2019-04-21T19:20:10.252810Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253516Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'auth_socket'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253548Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253555Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253562Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253570Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253577Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253608Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253638Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253650Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253658Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253665Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253672Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253678Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253685Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253691Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253697Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253704Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253710Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253716Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253723Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253729Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253735Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253741Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253747Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253753Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253760Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253766Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253772Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253778Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253784Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253790Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253796Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253802Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253809Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253815Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253821Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253828Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253834Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.253840Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2019-04-21T19:20:10.254042Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2019-04-21T19:20:10.254350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2019-04-21T19:20:10.355118Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-04-21T19:20:10.355620Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 190421 20:20:10
2019-04-21T19:20:12.019660Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 2524784
2019-04-21T19:20:12.021781Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2019-04-21T19:20:12.021816Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2019-04-21T19:20:12.021827Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2019-04-21T19:20:12.021838Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2019-04-21T19:20:12.021845Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2019-04-21T19:20:12.022091Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2019-04-21T19:20:12.022540Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

2019-04-21T19:20:14.298719Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-04-21T19:20:14.301162Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) starting as process 3146 ...
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308264Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308325Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308337Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308348Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308377Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308389Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308779Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-04-21T19:20:14.308910Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2019-04-21T19:20:14.311191Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-04-21T19:20:14.323593Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-04-21T19:20:14.326679Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-04-21T19:20:14.340441Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2019-04-21T19:20:14.504517Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-04-21T19:20:14.504663Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-04-21T19:20:14.609147Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-04-21T19:20:14.610411Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-21T19:20:14.610457Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2019-04-21T19:20:14.611636Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.25 started; log sequence number 2524784
2019-04-21T19:20:14.612018Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-04-21T19:20:14.612137Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2019-04-21T19:20:14.614451Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190421 20:20:14
2019-04-21T19:20:14.619157Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2019-04-21T19:20:14.619208Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2019-04-21T19:20:14.619226Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2019-04-21T19:20:14.619272Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2019-04-21T19:20:14.629863Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2019-04-21T19:20:14.630153Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
```

When I try running the `mysql_secure_installation` command it asks for the root password, but the system didn't prompt me to set one.

Could anyone advise what might be causing the problem with system not being able to execute the stat function and how to set the root password?

Comment: can you post the logs of mysql. Without that cant say anything.

Comment: @MohitMalviya, have added console output and contents of the error log. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: found answer to this issue?

Comment: @karthikeayan, no luck so far.